# Selecting rows from a list or other iterable but in order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a column named "ID"
I also have another dataframe with a list of ID values that I want to use.I can select a sub dataframe with the rows corresponding to the IDs in the list

For example

```
IDlist_df=pd.DataFrame({"v":[3,4,6,9]})
df=pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,9],"name":['menelaus','helen','ulyses','paris','hector', 'priamus','hecuba','andromache','achiles','ascanius','eneas','ajax','nestor','helenus']})


selected_lines=df[df['ID'].isin(IDlist_df['v'])]
print(selected_lines)
```

With this I get

```
    ID        name
3    3       paris
4    3      hector
5    4     priamus
6    4      hecuba
7    4  andromache
9    6    ascanius
10   6       eneas
13   9     helenus
```

I got a sub dataframe with the rows with ID 3,4,6,9

So far so good.

However, if I want to maintain the order and I have

```
IDlist_df=pd.DataFrame({"v":[3,9,6,4]})
```

I get the same result as above.

How can I get something like

```
    ID        name
3    3       paris
4    3      hector
13   9     helenus
9    6    ascanius
10   6       eneas
5    4     priamus
6    4      hecuba
7    4  andromache
```

(You can see that the order 3,9,6,4 is being maintained)

Comment: `df[df['ID'].isin(IDlist_df['v'])]`

Comment: My mistake @jezrael. Apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values in `IDlist_df.v` column are unique is possible use `rename` with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = IDlist_df.rename(columns={'v':'ID'}).merge(df, on='ID')
print (df)
   ID        name
0   3       paris
1   3      hector
2   9     helenus
3   6    ascanius
4   6       eneas
5   4     priamus
6   4      hecuba
7   4  andromache
```

Comment: Wow, interesting. So `merge` eliminates the rows that are not in the list?

Comment: @KansaiRobot - exactly. It is intersection of columns, but because duplicates in `df` get all rows.

Comment: No problem. Very elegant, I applied it already

Answer (score 0):

Find way to preserve index

```
(selected_lines.reset_index().set_index('ID').loc[[3, 9, 6, 4]]
 .reset_index().set_index('index').rename_axis(''))
```

result:

```
    ID  name
3   3   paris
4   3   hector
13  9   helenus
9   6   ascanius
10  6   eneas
5   4   priamus
6   4   hecuba
7   4   andromache
```

---

**other way**

sort_values with category

```
lst = [3, 9, 6, 4]
selected_lines.sort_values('ID', key=lambda x: pd.Categorical(x, categories=lst, ordered=True))
```